# Error message "uname.exe" has stopped working when I open Git Bash

Tags: git, bash, ssh, bitbucket

For some days I have had a strange problem with my Git Bash installation: Whenever I run Git Bash, I immediately receive the error message "`uname.exe`" has stopped working, and a stackdump is created.

I am working with Windows 7 64-bit and have re-installed the latest versions of both cygwin (64-bit) and Git Bash since the error first occured. I have also changed the passwd file in cygwin's `/etc` directory in order to point to my home directory located in `C:\Users\Michael`.

The strange thing is: The error first occured when I deleted the Default public key (`SSH`) on bitbucket.org, and copied my key in `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to bitbucket. However, I figure this can hardly be the reason for my installation not working anymore, can it?

Any clues what is wrong with my Git Bash?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Git Bash with TortoiseGit, what happens when you install plain regular Cygwin and run Git from there instead of using Git Bash? I hazard it could be a problem with the Cygwin environment installed by Git for Windows.

Comment: If I use the Cygwin environment and run Git from there everything works like a charm. It seems as if Git Bash were broken. Strangely, even a full re-installation of Git Bash won't help...